# Why is Object.keys faster than hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript, performance

```
 // hasOwnProperty approach 
 for (key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    value = obj[key];
  }
}

// Object.keys approach 
keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
  value = obj[keys[i]];
}
```

According to jsperf the Object.keys approach is 50%+ faster http://jsperf.com/object-keys-vs-hasownproperty/45

Why is this?

Comment: Your test might not be what you're expecting, a simple optimization would do : `keys = Object.keys(obj); value = obj[keys[keys.length - 1]];` bypassing your loops. In the first test, it do a check on each loop, as the second is only filling a variable with the value

Comment: Well obviously the plain `for in` needs to do more than `Object.keys`, and additionally filtering for `hasOwnProperty` is even more work.

Comment: Perhaps because `Object.keys` is only called once whereas `hasOwnProperty` is called several times (once for each enumerable property and once for each non-enumerable property). More functions calls means slower code. Also, `Object.keys` is a native function. Hence, in all probability it is faster than a JavaScript shim for the same.

Comment: Another simpler test here: [https://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-vs-in](https://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-vs-in). Seems like checking for `truthy` values using `[]` is much much faster than `in` or `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: For my sanity, can someone provide confirmation (ideally with a source) that the results are identical both ways?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

- `Object.keys` looks up all *own*, *enumerable* properties (oh, and arrays are fast).
- `for in` additionally looks up inherited *enumerable* properties, not only own ones
- `for in` + `hasOwnProperty` additionally tests all looked up properties for whether they are own properties.

Even if there are no inherited enumerable properties, it is still more work to do than not.

Comment: Your answer is clean and easy to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the tests in that thread show `hasownproperty` to be faster than `Object.keys()`. However, for those tests, the amount of properties to cycle through is small (<20 properties).

Wherever the number of object properties is large (no exact number, tests with >100 keys showed `Object.keys()` as a clear winner), `Object.keys()` beats it.

See https://jsperf.com/object-keys-vs-hasownproperty/55. You can go to the bottom of the page to see all revisions to the testing.

Comment: I don't know what the deal is, but starting with revision 47, it's showing that 'hasOwnProperty' to be the fastest. 9,809,798 vs 3,712,304.