# Difference between hasOwnProperty and obj.key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

When I have an object like var user =  { name : 'Tom'}; what is the difference when using the following instruction?

```
if (!user.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
//Some code
}
vs
if (!user.name) {
//some code
}
```

Is there any reason to prefer one way to the other?

Comment: what do you think about the result if `user = { name : false }` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Object.keys faster than hasOwnProperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326452/why-is-object-keys-faster-than-hasownproperty)

Comment: The former checks the existence of the own property of an object, the latter checks the value of any property in an object, including the properties in the prototype. The latter check can produce false positives, if the purpose of the check is to check the own properties only, and definitely fails when a property contains a falsy value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is that `hasOwnOroperty()` only checks for properties specifically assigned to the object. `user.name` on the otherhand will also check against metaproperies of the object. In this case it will not make a difference because I don't think objects have built-in name properties.

Comment: `function` object has `name` property, some HTML elements can have `name` property, `window` object has it ...

Comment: @Teemu thank you. More reason to use hasOwnProperty() then.

Answer (score 0):

he key difference is that in will return true for inherited properties, whereas hasOwnProperty() will return false for inherited properties. For example, the Object base class in JavaScript has a **proto** property, a constructor property, and a hasOwnProperty function.